# Avoid constructing a new object if it is a parameter and could be modified instead

Tags: c++

I have some code like this, where vec is some kind of vector-class:

```
Vec Vec::choose(const Vec& ifPositive, const Vec& ifNegative) const {
    Vec out(mSize);
    for(int index = 0; index < mSize; ++index) {
        if(mData[i] > 0)
            out[i] = ifPositive[i];
        else
            out[i] = ifNegative[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Now this code works fine in general, but if the left hand side of the function is one of the arguments, there are some unnecessary constuctor/destructor calls:

```
curVal =  trigger.choose(posVal, curVal); // construct is called in choose, then old curVal is destroyed
```

Is there some way to improve/avoid this, like if the compiler sees when the left-hand-side of the function is one of the parameters it would run a different code?

Edit:
Here is some sample code: http://ideone.com/nPUK3h

I'd like to know if its possible to ommit the last (4.) construction. 
I'll compile this with some more sophisticated optimizations later at home.

Edit2: 
I can avoid the additional construction if I introduce the following additional function:

```
Vec& Vec::setNegative(Vec& target, const Vec& ifNegative) const {
   for(int index = 0; index < mSize; ++index) {
        if(mData[index] <= 0)
            target[index] = ifNegative[index];
    }
    return target;
}
```

So if the lhs of the choose-function is the same as the first parameter this produces the same output, however if the lhs is another vector i would like to get a new vector instead.

Is there some way to choose between the two via some template-magic or compiler-technology??

Comment: Use a sane compiler that supports RVO.

Comment: Does it actually make the redundant copies? Depending on your compiler, optimisation level, and the structure of your calling code, you might find that it elides some or all of the redundancy you're worried about.

Comment: I don't see you using `ifNegative` anywhere in the function. Typo?

Comment: You might want to offer an in-place `merge_if_negative` function or so that mutates one of the vectors, but that would be somewhat different.

Comment: @jrok: thx, it was indeed a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, RVO permits the compiler to construct the return value in the location of the receiving object, but in this case, a reference to that object is being used in the call, i.e. the return value is being constructed before the parameter is used.

So I can see how this would defeat RVO. I can't see why it would defeat moving though.

Comment: If you add a move constructor that writes to cout, you can see that being called.

Comment: If I change the last line to Vec valC = trigger.choose(valA, valB); I still get four constructors called

Comment: I see your point, the additional constructor can indeed not be avoided within the function - but it could be eliminated via another function with a similar interface. But then the question would be how two choose between the two functions depending on the condition whether parameter1 is the same vector as the left-hand-side of the function.

Comment: The answer to that question would be...you can't :) which is why many STL algorithms invoke UB on overlapping ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Use a C++11 compiler with move semantics. The returned `Vec` object is nameless, and can be moved from.

Keep in mind that the code as written is strongly exception-safe. If any assignment fails, `curVal` is untouched. Any "optimization" which works by modifying `curVal` on the fly is likely to break this.

Comment: I get the same behaviour on VS2012, which does support move semantics. Has the constructor somehow stopped RVO? I thought RVO was still possible in C++11.

Comment: I get four constructions on gcc 4.6.3 too. If I add a move constructor I get four, and the move.

Comment: Four? That's a lot in any case.